# Stage value isnt adding up when players are touching the part

Tags: lua, roblox

So this is in roblox studio so uhh.. Im kinda new so... idrk how to fix this here's the code.
imma explain tha code so uhh..
players should touch the checkpoints which is in workspace.Checkpoints
when they touch those the Stage.Value should add + 1
then when they reach 30, they'll touch a part that will move them in the winner leaderboard
that would add up too.. so uhh

it seems like nothing is happening and no errors are found in the console

```
local Checkpoints = workspace.Checkpoints

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local Stage = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    Stage.Name = "Stage"
    Stage.Value = nil

    local Wins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    local WinnerArea = workspace.Checkpoints.WinSpawn
    Wins.Name = "Wins"
    Wins.Parent = leaderstats
    Wins.Value = 0

    WinnerArea.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        if tonumber(Stage.Value) == 30 then
            Wins.Value = Wins.Value + 1
            Stage.Value = 0
        end
    end)

    local lastCheckpointName = ""  -- Store the name of the last touched checkpoint

    for _, checkpoint in pairs(Checkpoints:GetChildren()) do
        checkpoint.Touched:Connect(function(hit)

            if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local char = hit.Parent

                -- Ensure the player is the owner of the character
                if char.Parent == plr.Character then

                    if tonumber(checkpoint.Name) == Stage.Value then
                        lastCheckpointName = checkpoint.Name  -- Store the name of the last touched checkpoint
                        Stage.Value = Stage.Value + 1
                        
                        
                    elseif checkpoint.Name == "MainObbySpawn" then
                        Stage.Value = 0

                        lastCheckpointName = checkpoint.Name  -- Store the name of the last touched checkpoint
                    end
                end
            end
        end)
    end

    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        wait()
        local checkpointToMoveTo = Checkpoints:FindFirstChild(lastCheckpointName)
        if checkpointToMoveTo then
            
            char:MoveTo(checkpointToMoveTo.Position)
        elseif Checkpoints:FindFirstChild("MainObbySpawn") then
            char:MoveTo(Checkpoints:FindFirstChild("MainObbySpawn").Position)
        end
    end)
end)
```

so i tried fixing some variables and relying on ai haha... nothing happens even the console isnt showing any errors regarding to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are trying to see if `Workspace` *is* `plr.Character`.

You set `char = hit.Parent` then check if `char.Parent == plr.Character` - essentially checking if `hit.Parent.Parent == plr.Charcter`
which it will not.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank u for the feedback but i cant understand it much ;w;
like how did i compare workspace from plr.character haha im reallyyyyy sorryyy i dont seem to understand

Comment: In line 32 you check if `char.Parent == plr.Character` and since you set `char` to `hit.Parent` in line 29 and hit will be the part of `plr.Character` that touches the baseplate so `hit.Parent` is `plr.Character`  so when you check if `char.hit == plr.Charcter` you are checking if `plr.Character.Parent == plr.Charcter` in short changing line 32 to `if hit.Parent == plr.Character then` should fix the problem with checkpoints and wins not increasing. If you give me a detailed description of what you want the script to do, I can try making it for you.

Comment: thank youuu soo muchh, i understand it now ^v^
bro, have a nice day